# How to read data from BLE using android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I developed demo app for communicate BLE. Now i can read and write data with BLE. When I read data some time I getting String some time I getting data like this `P����������`

```
 final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();

        try {
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                String messageString = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                Log.v("MessageString", messageString);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + messageString);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: first check characteristic UUIDs with your UUIDs

Comment: I checked both are same

Comment: Why don&#39;t you check serialized data on server side as well as client side matching or not.